# Login using passport not return bearer token instead - Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-passport

I am facing a problem where when I tried to login in postman, the data return after login is not a bearer token but such like this

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "User login succesfully, Use token to authenticate.",
    "token": {
        "name": "passport_token",
        "abilities": [
            "*"
        ],
        "tokenable_id": 1,
        "tokenable_type": "App\\Models\\User",
        "updated_at": "2022-07-04T08:52:22.000000Z",
        "created_at": "2022-07-04T08:52:22.000000Z",
        "id": 6
    }
}
```

Below is the login API

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->only(['email', 'password']);

    $validate_data = [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:8',
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($input, $validate_data);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'Please see errors parameter for all errors.',
            'errors' => $validator->errors()
        ]);
    }

    // authentication attempt
    if (auth()->attempt($input)) {
        $token = auth()->user()->createToken('passport_token')->accessToken;

        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'User login succesfully, Use token to authenticate.',
            'token' => $token
        ], 200);
    } else {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'User authentication failed.'
        ], 401);
    }
}
```

How to get the bearer token instead of the json like that since I also not found the way in documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Try change `accessToken` to `plainTextToken`

```
-------
$token = auth()->user()->createToken('passport_token')->plainTextToken;

        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'User login succesfully, Use token to authenticate.',
            'token' => $token,
            'tokenType' => 'Bearer'
        ], 200);
---------
```

Hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

That's weird behaviour of passport package, even though we follow the documentation. However if you want to generate the token then you can do it by following LOC.

```
$resultToken = $user->createToken($user->email);
```